# I have a list of quotes put into bullet list form. Should quotation marks be used on each line or is there another punctuation format?

Tags: quotes, lists

**Here's my example text:**

Some typical examples from the 89 suggestions related to youth include the following:

- “Re-store boys & girls camp for our youth”
- “Would be helpful to have an activity area for our youth in the community. Preferable some type of boys & girls club”
- “Have summer jobs for kids instead of have the JOM funds being spend by the school”
- “Childcare in Cibecue”
- “Give out rewards for kids who speak Apache”
- “Have more Apache classes in school so the young generation will learn”
- “Get more help for neglected kids and that live with grandparents”

Comment: If you want to make it clear that these are verbatim suggestions then formatting them as individual quotes seems a clear format.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you make it clear that they are verbatim quotes in the preceding sentence you shouldn't need to quote every bullet point (so long as all are actually direct quotes). However, if you were to cite each or any quote directly after (i.e. "quote" - John Doe) then the quotation marks would be required.